# find string in several opened workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How to find a string in several opened workbooks and color the row. String  can be duplicate in every sheet and can appear in Column A, B or C. Can this code be adapted for more workbooks?
I found this code for one workbook:

```
        Sub Search_String()

    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim Escolhe_Cor As Long
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    ' Set Search value
    SearchString = InputBox("Digite o número a ser procurado")
    Escolhe_Cor = InputBox("Escolha uma cor para destacar esse número. De 3 a 56")
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    ' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            ' if found, remember location
            FirstFound = cl.Address
            ' format found cell
            Do
                cl.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
                cl.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = Escolhe_Cor
                ' find next instance
                Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                ' repeat until back where we started
            Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to continue your question...

Comment: Hi, Can this code be adapted for more workbooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the information you provided, it looks like you just need to add you current code to a loop. This will look at every open workbook, so if you don't want to apply this to all of them, a regular expression to identify the workbook name could be used.

```
For Each wb In Workbooks
   'If you only want certain open workbooks searched use this If statement:
   If wb.name = *criteria* Then
      wb.Activate
     'run your code that loops through each sheet
   End If
Next wb
```